# New Jedis Client Does Not Work In Static Java Method

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Why does this same piece of code have different results?

I'm using Jedis 2.1.0 to create connections to Redis.

**METHOD A:**

```
private static Jedis getNewJedis() {
        return new Jedis(hostname,port);
    }

.....
public static main(String[] args){
     getNewJedis().ping();
}
```

**METHOD B:**

```
public static main(String[] args){
     new Jedis(hostname,port).ping();
}
```

I'm thinking the difference is Method A has been tucked away in a static method for ease of reuse, and hence should have the same effect as Method B when invoked.

Instead, I get an exception when I use Method A. Method B works fine!

**METHOD A Exception**:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:134)   at
>   redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:69)    at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:86)    at
>   redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.ping(BinaryClient.java:82)   at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.ping(Jedis.java:34)     at
>   org.tripodwire.esme.receiver.ReceiverProducer.produceTestJedis(ReceiverProducer.java:168)
>     at org.tripodwire.esme.entry.Entry.main(Entry.java:25)

Comment: where are hostname and port coming from?

Comment: There will be something else wrong. I'd recommend looking at the values of hostname and port and seeing if they are different between the two versions. Chances are you omitted the code from your question that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Bringer128 - You are both absolutely right. Apparently the port values are different at each invocation. So silly of me to not figure this out initially!